# Dynamic creation of class instances

Tags: vb.net, class, object, dynamic, instantiation

Is there any way to create class instances on the fly and refer to them later? I have a class with various methods and properties designed to hold & calculate product data. I'd like the application to be able to handle as many individual products as the user needs. This code clearly won't work but it should give you an idea of what I'm asking:

```
For x = 1 To howEverMany

    Dim product_ & x.ToString() As New myProductClass

Next x
```

I appreciate this may not be the best approach (I should probably use lists or arrays to hold the product data) but I'm curious as to whether this is possible from a technical standpoint. I'm using VB.Net but answers in any .Net language will be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: sure, it is possible. for instance if you have classes stored in another .NET assembly, you can reflect the assembly and instantiate the class and refer to it and invoke it later, absolutely. but you need to give us more information. Are these classes in your existing project? you may want to make it more OO perhaps and have some factory method to create the right type of class depending on parameters.

Comment: Use an array instead of `product_X`?

Comment: Thanks. The main thing is that the number of instances of the class that will be needed is variable - the user might require any number and I need to be able to call methods and set properties in any of these distinct class instances. Specifically the user loads in data from an unknown number of Excel files & I'm wondering if it's technically possible (even if not ideal) to instantiate a class representing the data in each workbook. The class is already defined in my project.

Comment: Thanks MicroVirus but as I said this is more of an "I wonder if...?" question than an actual problem. I'm already using arrays :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store them in a `List(Of T)`. Then you can LINQ one or more objects in the list.

```
'class level
Private Products As New List(Of myProductClass)

'place where you load them
For x As Integer = 1 To howEverMany
  Dim myc As New myProductClass
  mpc.Id = x
  'set other properties as needed
  Products.Add(mpc)
Next
```

Get one by it's Id:

```
Dim mpc4 = (From p In Products Where p.Id = 4).FirstOrDefault
If Not mpc4 Is Nothing Then
  'object exists
End If
```

You can make other similar queries on your List as well.